# Ingress server snippet

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I can't seem to find good documentation on the scripting language that goes into the Nginx Ingress server snippet. (annotation "ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet")

I can't find what language is used in there. I want to do some logging in there to stdout, also can I replace that with something like javascript?

Is anyone using good resources for this I can't seem to find?

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of "ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet" is to add some custom Nginx configuration which is not added by the ingress controller by default or using other annotations.
The good starting point to learn what can be done with this annotation is the [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).
Since you can't configure nginx with javascript it's not possible to use js there.

Comment: what language can we add in snippets annotation ?